# Alpine.js Cant bind x-data to functin in external js file

Tags: javascript, html, parcel, alpine.js

I'm creating an app with alpine.js

this is the context of my `index.html` file

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Hello Alpine</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="app" x-data="app()">
      <div>
        <button x-on:click="open">Open</button>

        <div x-show="isOpen()" x-on:click.away="close">
          // Dropdown
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="src/index.js"></script>
    <script>
      function app() {
        return {
          show: false,
          open() {
            this.show = true;
          },
          close() {
            this.show = false;
          },
          isOpen() {
            return this.show === true;
          }
        };
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

This code is working fine, but however, if I move the `app` function to `index.js` I'm getting an error in the console.

index.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Hello Alpine</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="app" x-data="app()">
      <div>
        <button x-on:click="open">Open</button>

        <div x-show="isOpen()" x-on:click.away="close">
          // Dropdown
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="src/index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

and index.js

```js
import "./styles.css";
import "alpinejs";

function app() {
  return {
    show: false,
    open() {
      this.show = true;
    },
    close() {
      this.show = false;
    },
    isOpen() {
      return this.show === true;
    }
  };
}
```

When I run this code, I get the following error:

> alpine.js:1907 Uncaught TypeError: app is not a function
> at eval (eval at tryCatch.el.el (alpine.js:NaN), :3:54)

CodeSandbox Link is [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/interesting-albattani-zewcv?file=/index.html:0-384)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By default, alpine is going to look for the component in the window level. So the issue can be solved by making an `app` variable in the window which is your exact same function.

```js
import "./styles.css";
import "alpinejs";

window.app = function () {
  return {
    show: false,
    open() {
      this.show = true;
    },
    close() {
      this.show = false;
    },
    isOpen() {
      return this.show === true;
    }
  };
};
```

There's a free video tutorial about extracting alpine js components in `Laracasts`, you can view it [here](https://laracasts.com/series/alpine-essentials/episodes/5).